# Where is an easy J2EE demo war/ear file I can deploy?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Looking for a simple J2EE war/ear that can be deployed that is bare-bones but does a simple read-write to an Oracle db. I'm happy to configure the database or run scripts to make the relevant table. Need something today to prove to a third party host and use to compare against our own apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get Java EE samples applications from the [GlassFish Samples](https://glassfish-samples.dev.java.net/) project.

Comment: No longer exists.  Any other thoughts?